# Building a product hierarchy using python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to build a product hierarchy import file for product management software, we just purchased.

```
                import pandas as pd
                df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\david.han\Desktop\Test.xlsx')
                df2.head()
```

This is the initial excel file i pulled

[image]

```
           my First attempt was to set index based on columns StyleMaster and StyleColor 
           df2.set_index(['StyleMaster', 'StyleColor'])
```

My Result came out like this

[image]

The expected resulted I'm looking for is shown below:

[image]

On Column ID, The Root ID would be StyleMaster, Follow by StyleColor (11101 (black), 111108(royal blue), then Variant SKU. On Column Parent ID, the root will be StyleMaster follow by Color. Column C is the indication on column ID,
1111 = Style, 111101 = Color, 111101XXS - Size. I'm trying to avoid by doing any manual intervention. OPen to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using python, i've developed a hierarchy strcuture using SQL union. This allowed me to remove any duplicate values.